# Get groups and users from LDAP

Tags: java, ldap

Hi i am trying to fetch all posixGroup from LDAP and the users in this group. Code below is what i have done so far, it returns me all the groups but i am not sure how to get the users for these groups. Please guide me is this approach good? or should i go by first getting the users and then based on GID get the group name?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ldap://192.168.*.*:389");
        env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "com.sun.jndi.url"); 
        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore"); 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple"); 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=manager,dc=*,dc=*"); 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "****");

        DirContext ctx;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        NamingEnumeration results = null;
        try {

            SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
            controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

            results = ctx.search("ou=path,dc=*,dc=*", "(objectClass=posixGroup)",controls);
            // Go through each item in list
            while (results.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult nc = (SearchResult)results.next();
                Attributes att=     nc.getAttributes();                           
                System.out.println("Group Name "+ att.get("cn").get(0));
                System.out.println("GID "+ att.get("GidNumber").get(0));
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error : "+e);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if (results != null) {
                try {
                    results.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error : "+e);
                }
            }
            if (ctx != null) {
                try {
                    ctx.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error : "+e);
                }
            }
        }      

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Querying all users in a group

It depends which attribute is used by groups in your directory to denote membership. `posixGroup` uses `memberUid` with the username as value (defined in [RFC 2307](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2307)). There are other possible attributes (member, uniquemember) and values (DN) so check what your directory uses.

So in order to load all users from a group, you would have to:

1. Query that group, for example with this filter `(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(cn=<group name>))`
2. Iterate through all values of `memberUid` in the group, for each:
3. Query the user object with `(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=<memberUid>))`
4. Then you can access user attributes like `uidNumber`.

This is not a very efficient way of doing it because it will generate lots of small queries, but as far as I know, LDAP has no means to join a group entry with the user entries it references in a single result (unlike SQL).

You could optimise it a bit by limiting results to the attributes you actually need: `gidNumber` for the group query and `uidNumber` for the user query. Using either [`SearchControls.setReturningAttributes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/SearchControls.html#setReturningAttributes%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) or a version of [`DirContext.search()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/DirContext.html#search%28javax.naming.Name,%20javax.naming.directory.Attributes,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) that takes a `attributesToReturn` argument. It doesn't reduce the number of queries though, only the volume of data returned.

### Some more general notes about LDAP usage

- If your queries have a large number of results (for example "all users"), you might hit your directory's result size limit (typically 5000) and only get partial results.
- When modifying group membership information, you have to update both `posixAccount` and `posixGroup` objects (unless your directory server does it, but I doubt it will), otherwise it becomes inconsistent.

Comment: i see thanks. But what i just did was changes the group ID of some posixAccount and didn't update the group. So my user has a GID of that group but the poisxGroup doesn't have anything which says that this user is my member. So how do i handle that case?

Comment: That's y i was thinking of going the other way around like getting the user's list first and then based on GID get the groups

Comment: You have to update group membership both in posixAccount and posixGroup objects (unless your directory server does it, but I doubt it will), otherwise it becomes inconsistent as you found out. You can also load users first, though mind your directory's result size limit if you query all users.

Comment: oh is see. So seems like i was doing wrong and i can expect that if the server is configured properly. Then the group will have all the members in it.

Comment: so if i go by memberUid, then do i have to search again? Cause i need the UID also for that user

Comment: cause the memberUid will only give me the name not the UID number, which is also require

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, you have to query each UID to load the posixAccount object of each user. If you only need a few user attributes like the number, you can limit search results to just those attributes instead of the full posixAccount entry.

Comment: Is there any method to get the user based on UID directly without doing a search?

Comment: I am trying out: NamingEnumeration user = ctx.search("ou=**,dc=**,dc=**", "(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid="+uid+"))",controls);
      
      while(user.hasMore())
      {
       SearchResult userDetails = (SearchResult)user.next();
       Attributes userAttributes =userDetails.getAttributes();
       System.out.println("UID "+ userAttributes.get("uidNumber").get(0));
      }

Comment: But i think this will slow things down

Comment: As far as I know, you'll have to query for each UID. I agree that's not optimal. Maybe you could speed things up by limiting results to the uidNumber attribute with either [`SearchControls.setReturningAttributes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/SearchControls.html#setReturningAttributes%28java.lang.String[]%29) or using a version of [`DirContext.search()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/DirContext.html) that takes a `attributesToReturn` argument. It doesn't reduce the number of queries, only the volume of data returned.